# Reading Multiple values from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

i am having a xml file

```
<Actual-External-Terminals>
    <Actual-External-Terminal>
      <Party-Id value="EXTRA:77440" />
      <Name value="77440" />
      <Dial-String value="77440" />
      <IP-ISDN-SIP value="IP" />
      <Total-Connection-Time value="0s" />
      <Failing-Attempts value="0" />
      <Last-Failure-Cause value="N/A" />
      <List-of-Connection-Records>
        <Connection Call-Rate="768" Call-Type="Video" ConnectionTime="" Dialin-Dialout="Dial-in" Disconnection-Time="2012-02-16T13:33:32Z" Over-GW-port-limit="false" Over-MCU-port-limit="false" Reason-Disconnection="Normal" />
      </List-of-Connection-Records>
    </Actual-External-Terminal>
```

In the above xml i want to get all the value of connection section please help me out thanks 
can't use Linq to xml because its .net framework 2.0 and desktop App

regards
wasif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Xml is a way. As follows:

```
  using System.Xml;
// Name space & class declarations...
static void ReadXml(string filePath)
        {
            //These would be kept in a settings file but constants for this example
            const string CONNECTION_LISTING_NODE_NAME = "List-of-Connection-Records";
            const string CONNECTION_NODE_NAME = "Connection";
            const string CALL_RATE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "Call-Rate";

            //Load xml
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(filePath);
            var root = doc.FirstChild;
            var connectionRecordLists = doc.SelectNodes(String.Format("//{0}",CONNECTION_LISTING_NODE_NAME));
            if (connectionRecordLists == null) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < connectionRecordLists.Count; i++)
            {
                var connections = connectionRecordLists[i].SelectNodes(CONNECTION_NODE_NAME);
                if (connections == null) continue;
                for (var j = 0; j < connections.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (connections[j].Attributes != null
                        && connections[j].Attributes[CALL_RATE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME] != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(connections[j].Attributes[CALL_RATE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME].Value);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your xml file has a fixed element and attributes, what about XmlSerializer Class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.80).aspx